# Running end to end tests with Testcontainers with docker-compose inside Gitlab-ci

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

We've written end to end tests with Testcontainers. A docker-compose file is loaded with the following Testcontainers method :

```
@Container
    public static final DockerComposeContainer<?> COMPOSE_CONTAINER =
            new DockerComposeContainer<>(new File("src/test/resources/docker-compose-test.yml"))
                    .withLocalCompose(true)
                    .withExposedService(ZOOKEEPER_SERVICE, ZOOKEEPER_PORT)
                    .withExposedService(BROKER_SERVICE, BROKER_PORT)
                    .withExposedService(BROKER_SERVICE, BROKER_PORT_LOCALHOST)
                    .withExposedService(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SERVICE, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT)
                    .withExposedService(VAULT_SERVICE, VAULT_PORT)
                    .withExposedService(ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICE, ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_1)
                    .withExposedService(ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICE, ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_2)               
                    .waitingFor(ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICE, Wait.forHttp("/").forStatusCode(200))
                    .waitingFor(VAULT_SERVICE, Wait.forHttp("/").forStatusCode(200))
                    .waitingFor(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SERVICE, Wait.forHttp("/subjects").forStatusCode(200));
```

It works locally but it fails in our Gitlab-CI test stage. We tried to add docker-compose to the stage but it still doesn't work. The test stage has been written as follow :

```
test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - docker-compose --version
    - mvn clean test -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/src/main/resources/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${TRURST_STORE_PWD}
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: ./target/surefire-reports/*.xml
```

The error in the pipe is :

```
 Time elapsed: 101.927 s  <<< ERROR!
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Local Docker Compose not found. Is docker-compose on the PATH?
```

I hope someone has already set up something similar and will help us :)

Best regards.

Comment: Did you check the official documentation about using Testcontainers in Gitlab CI?

https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/

Answer (score 1):

Likely it's because you can't just use docker:dind since that's docker in docker, you need dcind which is docker compose in docker. I'm not sure if you can try docker:dcind or if there's another dcind image you can try out that's on docker hub.